# DEP0100 - deployment failed due to a developer licensing issue windows 10 while trying to remote a windows store app

Tags: windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2015, remote-debugging, windows-10

When I try to deploy a windows 10 app using remote debugger, I get this error "DEP0100 - deployment failed due to a developer licensing issue windows 10 while trying to remote a windows store app." 
From what I understand, there is no concept of windows developer licensing in windows 10, all I have to do is to enable developer mode from settings.
I have still tried to renew developer license using powershell. 
Is there any solution for this issue?

PS. Remote debugging was working earlier, it suddenly started giving this error.
Edit: This is happening only when remote debugger is running as a service.

Comment: Also see this question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36324300/ensure-that-target-device-has-developer-mode-enabled-could-not-obtain-a-develop

Answer (score 2):

This may seem like a really dumb solution, but I had the same issue and couldn't find what's wrong, until I enabled developer mode and it all worked.

## To enable developer mode on Windows 10:

1. Click Start
2. Type "For Developers Settings"
3. Switch to "Developer Mode"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about this, but make sure the account you're using to run the service is allowed to do developer stuff on your machine.
Here's what I would do:

1. Generate an account on the machine with admin rights (e.g.
   "myadminuser")
2. Log in as "myadminuser" and enable developer mode for
   that account on the machine. (You might have to provide a Microsoft
   account here) This will allow the account to install apps.
3. Configure the service to run with user "myadminuser".

I didn't try this, but this should work.

Comment: I did the same way. Still not working. I think this is a bug.