# Ensure that target device has developer mode enabled. Could not obtain a developer license due to error

Tags: visual-studio, raspberry-pi, iot, windows-10-iot-core, windowsiot

I am following [this tutorial](https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/KitBlinky.htm) and get the following error:

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error DEP0100 : Please ensure that target device has developer mode enabled. Could not obtain a developer license due to error 800704C7.
```

I am not sure how to do so in the `Raspberry Pi 3` (which I have fed its public `IP` in front of `Target Machine` in the `Debug` tab of `Properties` in the `solution explorer`.  I am debugging on the remote machine selecting `ARM` as the screenshot below shows. Any information is appreciated specially if you have experience with Windows 10 IoT core.

My laptop is running Windows 10 enterprise and I am using Visual Studio 2015 community edition. I am planning to run the Blinky example provided by MS IoT team remotely on the Raspberry Pi that already is running `Windows 10` insider edition.
[image]

Comment: When working with "Universal Apps" in Visual Studio, the XAML designer won't work if "Developer Mode" isn't enabled. So make sure your windows developer mode is enabled.

Comment: not sure why this downvoted. just solved my problem

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Solved the problem by going to the "For developers" settings dialog (you can search for it with this string in the "Start" button), and selecting the `developer mode` like the following screenshot.

[image]

Comment: What a useless error message; suggests the issue is with the IoT device, rather than indicating the problem is not having developer mode enabled locally...  Will file this as an issue against Visual Studio

Comment: If you've somehow lost that window:  "You can go to the For developers page at any time to enable or disable Developer Mode: simply enter "for developers" into the Cortana search box in the taskbar." [reference: Micosoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/enable-your-device-for-development)